# Attaching UITextField to NSUserDefaults

Tags: json, nsstring, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults, server

I am a beginner & I am trying to figure out how to upload text from a textfield to a server along with coordinates but I need to add the textfield to userdefaults.

The UITextfield is in my ViewController, while the coordinates & post to server are in a separate object class.

A tutorial or sample code will be very helpful.

Below, I have attached the relevant code I am using to upload the coordinates.

**What I need is help on adding and uploading text from UITextfield in another class to the code below.**

Singleton.m

```
@implementation Singleton {
    CLLocation *location;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setDouble:location.coordinate.latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
        [userDefaults setDouble:location.coordinate.longitude forKey:@"longitude"];

        [userDefaults synchronize];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) timerDidFire:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (([userDefaults doubleForKey:@"latitude"] != location.coordinate.latitude) || ([userDefaults doubleForKey:@"longtitude"] != location.coordinate.longitude)) {

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://setslocation.php"]];

        NSDictionary *requestData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude], @"longitude",
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude], @"latitude",
                                 nil];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestData options:0 error:&error];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        [userDefaults setDouble:location.coordinate.latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
        [userDefaults setDouble:location.coordinate.longitude forKey:@"longtitude"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first save your textfield value to NSUserDefaults and synchronize. You can get your value any where in your project from NSUserDefaults.

set value like:

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"your textfield value" forKey:@"your key name"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

get value:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"your key name"]);
```

make sure you write same key name.